# How to make a JSON-like QObject

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, moc, qproperty

In short, I want to make an JSON-like object, which is easily accessible to both QML / Qt C++ side.

In QML, I can make a `settings` object like this:

```js
Item {
    id: settings
    property alias snapshot: snapshot
    QtObject {
        id: snapshot
        property string saveDirectory: "~/hello/world/"
  }
}
```

And make it a singleton, now we can access data via  `settings.snapshot.saveDirectory` .

But accessing it in C++ is very inconvenience, so I'm trying to do this task in C++: create a class `Settings`, establish instance as `settings`, then pass it into `QQmlApplicationEngine` as a context. (the whole application only has only one instance of `Settings`)

## state.cpp

```cpp
// =============================================================
/// Settings is parent

class Settings : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(SnapshotSettings* snapshot READ snapshot)  // <- It's pointer, very important!
public:
    explicit Settings(QObject *parent=0) : m_snapshot_settings(new SnapshotSettings) {}
private:
    SnapshotSettings* m_snapshot_settings;
}

// =============================================================
// SnapshotSettings is the child of Settings

class SnapshotSettings : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString saveDirectory READ saveDirectory)
public:
    explicit Settings(QObject *parent=0) : m_save_directory("~/hello/world/") {}
private:
    QUrl m_save_directory;
}
```

## main.cpp

1. I register `SnapshotSettings*` type. Otherwise, it said:

   ```
   QMetaProperty::read: Unable to handle unregistered datatype 'SnapshotSettings' for property 'Settings::snapshot'
   main.qml:52: TypeError: Cannot read property saveDirectory' of undefined
   ```
2. `qmlRegisterType<>()`  seems unnecessary because I pass its instance into QML as a context, instead of instantialize it in QML?

```cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QtQml>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "state.cpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);


    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    Settings settings;

    // ....Am I right?
    qRegisterMetaType<SnapshotSettings*>("SnapshotSettings");

    // This seems unnecessary because I use its instance as a context?
    // qmlRegisterType<Settings>("com.aisaka.taiga", 0, 1, "Settings");

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("settings", &settings);
    engine.addImportPath(QStringLiteral(":/qml"));
    engine.load(QUrl("qrc:/qml/main.qml"));

    return app.exec();
}
```

> One told me I made an anti-pattern of C++/QML…, saying "I never see anyone do like this".

Now it **seems** ok, I can use `settings.snapshot.saveDirectory` in QML. But in QtCreator, **auto-completion work incorrectly.**(`saveDirectory` won't show after `settings.snapshot.`)

My question is:  Maybe I really did an anti-pattern? If yes, is there any better way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: what does that mean - auto-completion work incorrectly?

Comment: @folibis `saveDirectory` won't show after typing `settings.snapshot.`

Answer (score 0):

Your `snapshot` property needs to be of type `SnapshotSettings*`, i.e. a pointer to `SnapshotSettings` because that class is a QObject and cannot be copied.

You should also mark that property as `CONSTANT`, since the pointer never changes.

The `saveDirectory` property will either need a `NOTIFY` signal or also `CONSTANT` depending on whether it can change during runtime.

Comment: 1. Sorry, that's a typo. I indeed have used `Q_PROPERTY(SnapshotSettings* ...)` , I forgot to add it when asking.

Comment: 2. I don't need its `NOTIFY` so it is omitted.

Comment: While a property without `NOTIFY` is effectively constant, as in not reevaluated, it is bad form to not state that explicitly and the QML engine will complain about that at runtime.
The general approach is fine though.
Btw, "~" is a shell shortcut for the home directory, it doesn't necessarily mean the same in an URL. Better user `QUrl::fromLocalFile()` to create an URL for a local path